# Do flask threads handle file access?

Tags: python, multithreading, flask

I am building a Flask app that uses a docx template to build a Word document. If I set `threaded=True` in `app.run()` will Flask handle the critical region properly as multiple users access the file on the server concurrently?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Flask doesn't know what your code does. It's up to you to put whatever checks you need before taking an action. HTTP is a stateless protocol, you cannot make assumptions about how and when workers will access other data.

`threaded=True` just enables multiple workers so that the development server can handle concurrent requests.